# How to get back to subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I have written a code to figure out if a particular set of programs are installed on a system. However after my code get stuck for mysql and if i manually exit mysql it returns not found despite MYSql being installed on my system

```
import subprocess
appium = subprocess.call("appium -v",stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
if appium == 0: # found
    print ("found")
elif appium == 1: # not found
    print ("not found")
elif appium > 1: # error
    print ("error")

mysql = subprocess.call("mysql.exe -uroot -proot",stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=False)
if mysql == 0: # found
    print ("found")
elif mysql == 1: # not found
    print ("not found")
elif mysql > 1: # error
    print ("error")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is caused by the fact that when you run mysql like, it waits for some input. 
And when you kill it it returns a 1 because the process did not terminate in a normal way. 
Have you tried to PIPE the stdin of you program and write 'exit\n' in it?

Comment: Thanks for the information. I finally decided to use 'mysql -h localhost -V'